# How to run new process after the old process finish, without hang the application

Tags: c#, multithreading, process

I working on Visual Studio 2010, C# (.Net 4).

I have an application that contain a DataGridView with two columns. Each column contain argument for the program I want to run.

Now I want to run from my C# application another application with parameters from the data grid view. In additional, I want to wait 3 seconds before running new process.

I try the follow code, but the process runs parallelly and not one after one:

```
private static Mutex mut = new Mutex();

public void runProgram(string executablePath, string argu1, string argu2)
{
    mut.WaitOne();

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(executablePath);
    startInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "/C " + set.ExecutablePath + " "
                            + argu1 + " " + argu2;

    try
    {
        Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
        //p.WaitForExit();  // don't start the next process until the first finish -> not good, stuck the app
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR: unsuccess to run the applicition");
    }

    mut.ReleaseMutex();
}

private void bu_RunProgram_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!File.Exists(set.ExecutablePath))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The executable file doesn't exist\nPlease select right executable file in the settings form", "Error");
        return;
    }

    int progRow;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dg_ParametersToRun.Rows)
    {
        progRow = dgvr.Index;
        string argu1 = dg_ParametersToRun.Rows[progRow].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString();
        string argu2 = dg_ParametersToRun.Rows[progRow].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString();
        
        Thread threadProgRun= new Thread(() => runProgram(set.ExecutablePath, argu1, argu2));
        threadProgRun.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(3000); // Need to come to this line only when the previous thread finish...
    }
}
```

I've never worked with threads before.

### Updated code

According the suggestion:

```
// Aid variable
int paramRowIndex;

public void runNextParameters(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    paramRowIndex++;
    if (paramRowIndex > dg_RunListTests.Rows.Count) return;   finish run all parameters

            //run the test
    string argu1 = dg_RunListTests.Rows[paramRowIndex].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString();
    string argu2 = dg_RunListTests.Rows[paramRowIndex].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString();
    runParameters(set.ExecutablePath, componenet, test);
}

public void runParameters(string executablePath, string argu1, string argu2)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(executablePath);
    startInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "/C " + set.ExecutablePath +  " "
                        + argu1 + " " + argu2;
    try
    {
        Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
        p.Exited += runNextParameters;
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unsuccess to run the test again");
    }
}

private void bu_RunParameters_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!File.Exists(set.ExecutablePath))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The executable file doesn't exist\nPlease select right     executable file in the settings form", Error);
        return;
    }

    paramRowIndex = 0;
    runNextParameters(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: Fill a List<> in your loop.  Use the Process.Exited event to step through the list.

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't try it yet, but it's really looking good !

Comment: @HansPassant: I try it, but it's doesn't work for me. Altough I added the Process.Exited event it's not come in... I update my question according to your suggestion.
And one more: How can I dealy between process in this way?
thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Possible fast solution: start a .bat file that starts the two(three) programs. You have to create another program that waits 3 seconds to call in between.